# Azure Data Factory V2: Event trigger with file name as variable

Tags: sql, azure, parameters, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to have a copy activity on ADF V2 trigged by an event in which the source file name is a variable? I know you should define default value for the "sourceFile" in the pipeline parameters (as we see below). However I would like to have no default value and have the pipeline trigged by any file with any title. In order words the file name would be checked at run time.

[image]

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hey @JayGong thanks for your answer! I ended up using the "Get Metadata" activity - which does the trick too! However - as you can see above - I have to pass a value to the "BlobName" above which is used by this REST_API activity. However - as this requires to be in Json, how to pass the value to the event trigger for this blob which is stored in a container? Btw the container is called "source-csv". Would the following work? "source-csv\@{triggerBody().filename}"                       Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I suggest you could get to know [Lookup Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) in Azure Data Factory.

> Lookup activity reads and returns the content of a configuration file
>   or table. It also returns the result of executing a query or stored
>   procedure. The output from Lookup activity can be used in a subsequent
>   copy or transformation activity if it's a singleton value. The output
>   can be used in a ForEach activity if it's an array of attributes.

Please see the [Copy Activity example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#copy-activity-example) in above doc.You could store the file name in a JSON file into Azure Blob Storage and JSON file is modified dynamically.The lookup activity will retrieve the specific filename and you could use it in expression: `@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output.firstRow.FileName`.